# Pointers in C, causing segfault

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I am having some issues understanding where my problem relies within my program. I am trying to send in the the head nodes of each corresponding doubly linked linked list(trash list and the main list), then return the new head node of the trash.

The main issue i am having is that after i go through this function to add the corresponding node to the trash list within the addTrash function, the next time I end up trying to use the main list at least for traversing it, it  segfaults.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct node {
    int value;
    struct node *next, *previous;
};

struct node * modifyMainList(struct node *mainHead, int link2Delete){

    printf("inside modify list\n\n");
    struct node *curr, *temp;
    temp = NULL;
    curr = mainHead;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < link2Delete; i++){

        printf("%d\n", i);
        curr = curr -> next;
    }

    if(curr -> previous == NULL){

        temp = curr;
        curr = curr -> next;

        curr -> previous = NULL;

        temp -> next = NULL;
        free(temp);

        return mainHead;
    }else{

        if((curr -> next == NULL) && (curr -> previous != NULL)){

            temp = curr;
            curr = curr -> previous;
            curr -> next = NULL;

            temp -> previous = NULL;
            free(temp);

            return mainHead;
        }else{

            temp = curr;
            curr = curr -> previous;
            curr -> next = curr -> next -> next;
            curr = temp -> next;
            curr -> previous = curr -> previous -> previous;

            temp -> previous = NULL;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            free(temp);

            return mainHead;            
        }
    }
}

struct node * addTrash(struct node *trashHead, struct node *mainHead, int link2Delete){

    struct node *curr = mainHead, *trashCurr = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < link2Delete; i++){

        curr = curr -> next;
    }

    printf("inside addTrash\n\n");
    if(trashHead == NULL){

        trashHead = curr;
        trashHead -> previous = NULL;
        trashHead -> next = NULL;


        return trashHead;

    }else{

        trashCurr = trashHead;
        while(trashCurr -> next != NULL){

            trashCurr = trashCurr -> next;
        }

        trashCurr -> next = curr;
        temp = curr;
        temp -> previous = trashCurr;
        temp -> next = NULL;

        temp = NULL;
        free(temp);

        trashCurr = NULL;
        free(trashCurr);

        return trashHead;

    }
}

//Traverses and prints out data from left to right
void TraverseLeftRight(struct node *head){

    struct node *current;
    current = head;

    while(1){
        if(current != NULL){

            printf("Left to right output:           %d\n", current -> value);
            current = current -> next;
        }else{
            break;
        }           
    }
}


//Traverses and prints out data from right to left
void TraverseRightLeft(struct node *tail){

    struct node *current;


    current = tail;

    while(1){
        if(current != NULL){

            printf("Right to left output:           %d\n", current -> value);
            current = current -> previous;
        }else{
            break;
        }           
    }
}


//inserts a node into the doubly linked linked-list
struct node * insertIntoList(struct node *head, int value){

    int i;
    struct node *current, *temp;

    for(i = 0; i < value; i++){

        //Case 1: List empty
        if (i == 0){

            //create node and assign all pointers and values
            temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp -> value = i;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            temp -> previous = NULL;
            head = temp;
            current = head; 
            printf("Input data:             %d\n", current -> value);


        }else{

            //create node and assign pointers and values
            temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            temp -> value = i;
            temp -> next = NULL;

            //assign pointer of previous for temp to the current node
            temp -> previous = current;



            //change current node to the node that was just created
            current -> next = temp;
            current = current -> next;  
            printf("Input data:             %d\n", current -> value);

        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return head;

}

//frees the data on the doubly linked linked-list

void Free(struct node *head){

    struct node *current, *temp;

    current = head;
    temp = head;    

    while(1){
        if(current != NULL){

            current = current -> next;
            temp -> next = NULL;
            temp -> previous = NULL;
            temp -> value = 0;
            free(temp);
            temp = current;

        }else{
            break;
        }           
    }


}

int main(int argv, char **argc){

    struct node *head, *current, *tail, *temp, *trashHead;
    int input, link2Delete = 0, size = 0, y = 0, number2Delete = 0, i;
    head = NULL;
    trashHead = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
    current = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

    //Check to see if there is the correct amount of arguments
    if(argv < 2){
          printf("************************************************\n");
          printf("* You must include a number for size of list.  *\n");
          printf("************************************************\n");

        //exit program
        return 0;

     }else{
        if(argv > 2){
            printf("*****************************************************************\n");
            printf("* You have entered too many arguments, arguments need to be 2.  *\n");
            printf("*****************************************************************\n");

            //exit program
            return 0;

        }else{

            if(argv == 2){

                //convert string to int
                input = atoi(argc[1]);

                //create the doubly linked linked-list
                head = insertIntoList(head, input); 



                //traverse and print values from left to right order
                TraverseLeftRight(head);

                //traverses the list to create the tail
                current = head;

                while(1){
                    if(current != NULL){
                        temp = current;
                        current = current -> next;

                    }else{
                        break;
                    }           
                }   

                tail = temp;

                printf("\n");               

                //traverse and print values from right to left order
                TraverseRightLeft(tail);

                //Generate the random numbers for the corresponding names to be deleted and the numbers of
                //deletions made
                srand( time(NULL) );
                size = input;
                number2Delete = rand() % size + 1;

                printf("\n\nThis is the random number: %d\n", rand());
                printf("This is the nuber of nodes to be deleted: %d\n", number2Delete);

                for(i = 0; i < number2Delete; i++){

                    y = 0;
                    //Pick a random node for deletion
                    link2Delete = (rand() % size);
                    current = head;
                    while(current != NULL){                 

                        current = current -> next;
                        if(current != NULL){
                            printf("this is node: %d\n", y);
                            y++;
                        }
                    }

                    printf("this is the node to be deleted: %d\n\n", link2Delete);
                    size--;

                    trashHead = addTrash(trashHead, head, link2Delete);
                    printf("this is the head of trash: %d\n\n", trashHead -> value);
                    head = modifyMainList(head, link2Delete);           
                }

                Free(head);
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `trashCurr = trashHead;
        while(trashCurr != NULL){

            trashCurr = trashCurr -> next;
        }

        trashCurr -> next = curr;` : When while-loop ends, `trashCurr` is `NULL`.

Comment: And in addition to adding to the trash list, it is necessary to reconfigure the link of the main list.

Comment: as in skipping over that node that was just added to the trash correct? if so, i just haven't gotten around to that. just trying to make sure the implementation of the trash list is correct

Comment: After fixing that issue, i guess within my logic of my code i am getting a infinite loop at line 247 with the traversing inside the while for main

Comment: skip..yeah. Removing B from list A<->B<->C must be A<->C.

Comment: yeah, just haven't done that portion of the code quite yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in `addTrash` is here:

```
for(i = 0; i < link2Delete; i++){
```

You need to protect against assigning a NULL pointer to `trashHead`, e.g.

```
for(i = 0; curr -> next && i < link2Delete; i++){
```

**Example Output**

```
$ ./bin/llmaintrash 5
Input data:             0
Input data:             1
Input data:             2
Input data:             3
Input data:             4
Input data:             5

left to right output:      0
left to right output:      1
left to right output:      2
left to right output:      3
left to right output:      4
left to right output:      5

Right to left output:           5
Right to left output:           4
Right to left output:           3
Right to left output:           2
Right to left output:           1
Right to left output:           0


This is the random number: 1524010487
This is the number of nodes to be deleted: 1
this is node: 0
this is node: 1
this is node: 2
this is node: 3
this is node: 4
this is the node to be deleted: 4

this is the head of trash: 4
```

---

As an additional note, you can also significantly shorten your traversal functions, e.g.:

```
void traverseLeftRight (struct node *head) 
{
    for (struct node *current = head; current; current = current->next)
        printf ("left to right output: %6d\n", current -> value);
}
```

Comment: It wont become a Null with the implimentation, because the link2Delete never becomes larger than the size of the list with the setup that i have done, if it ever becomes Null is because of the index becoming null because of incorrect pointer handling corresponding to each node.

Comment: Although that might be an issue, i am pretty positive i did the adding correct and it should not have changed the original linked list, since i have not explicitly tried to change that within the addTrash function.

Comment: Your problem is assigning `curr = curr -> next;`, `curr->next` is ALWAYS `NULL` for the final node.

Comment: yes i understand that, but if you look at the implimentation, it will never get to the final node to assign the  curr = curr -> next; because it will get to the n index and break before it enters that loop. unless my implimentation is incorrect.

Comment: I do see you limiting with `% size`, but running though a debugger, you crash because you assign `NULL` to `trashHead` at that point. Now I didn't backtrack through the entire code, I implemented a protection against ever doing so regardless what you pass as `link2delete` (so long as `head` is valid). There are most likely a number of other issues there, and I'll pick through as time permits. Also `trashHead` is always passed as `NULL` given `trashHead = NULL;` in `main`.

Comment: I do appreciate the help though, just saying i took that into account when I was building that portion of the code so it would not cause that issue. But as far as what happens with the code. for some reason it hits a infinite loop during the 2nd iteration of the code within either of the while loops within main or within addTrash, these while loops for some reason are coming up with both of the lists

Comment: I think I also see where you are getting surprised, I enter `5` in response to your `size of list` **prompt** and then you output nodes `0-5` that is **six** nodes `:)` (which would explain why `link2delete` is one larger than expected resulting in the iteration of `1` too many times causing `NULL` to be assigned to `trashHead`.)

Comment: yeah that is just a <= within my insertIntoList function that i missed

Comment: List are fairly straight forward, but there is a lot to them. Your coding style makes debugging a bit more challenging because we are not limiting the potential errors to list operations, but what may be the side effect of user input and logic related thereto. You are doing well, but as you can see, when taking input, generating random occurrences, all while trying to implement lists for the first time can involve a *lot* of work `:)`

Comment: Yeah, I think most of my issues are more of the implimentation of pointers than really anything else other than a couple of smaller logic errors here and there.

Comment: Your use of pointers if fine. You just have to make sure you are validating values you send to list functions, and **above all**, you must protect against attempting to dereference a `NULL` pointer (that one will kill you every time). Why? the address is `0x0` (way at the bottom of the system protected memory area).

Comment: I just did a update to the program also with the list modification function. But i feel like it still is something to do with the pointers because after the first iteration it will crash at the index within the modify list (it is functioning like it that index was deleted from the list entirely).

Comment: You have significant logic errors in your updated `addTrash` function. First, what does `temp = NULL; free (temp);` do? Also, `trashHead = addTrash(trashHead...` only changes when `trashHead` is `NULL`. You have problems in `modifyMainList` (e.g. when `link2Delete = 2`) causes `if(curr -> previous == NULL)` to test `TRUE`. That can only happen if the `curr->previous` pointers are messed up. You will have to step through your code carefully with `gdb` (just compile with `-g`, then `gdb ./yourprog`, then, e.g., `set args 5`, `break main` and `run` and then examine where things go wrong.

Comment: temp = NULL and free(temp) that is suppose to free up the memory allocated to those locations of memory so you do not have a memory leak.

the reason for the curr -> previous == NULL check is to check for the case of the head node getting deleted, because you have your cases of head and every other nodes.

Comment: But you can't assign `temp = NULL` and then `free (temp)` -- What do you think that frees? (hint -- the order of your setting to `NULL` and `free` is reversed -- but you cannot free what you are attempting to free) Also, don't take the `gdb` reference wrong, you are doing great, but at this point, what needs to be done is step through the code to confirm all values one by one -- that is a bit broad. If you can work though it and narrow, or eliminate a bulk of the cruft, that will help me help you with any specific problem. (Where is the problem in 320 lines is a bit broad) Keep at it `:)`

Comment: The fact that `curr -> previous == NULL` when `link2Delete = 2` is a good place to start, print out all `prev`, `node` and `next` pointers (using `%p`) and validate all pointers point to where you think they do. When I hit problems like this, I pull out a *pencil and paper*, draw my nodes and the pointers linking them and then go to my code to verify I'm really filling, deleting, moving, etc... what I think I am. You are on the right track, you just have more work to do. If I had the answer, I'd give it to you, but I'm not pulling out the pencil and paper `:)`

Comment: Okay, well i appreciate the help immensely. Thank you! Have a good one!

Comment: For you logic issues, I've put a pastebin link for a [**Doubly Linked Circular Linked List w/void Payload**](https://pastebin.com/y4qKsC8x) for you. Note the list is **circular** (last points to first, first->prev points to last). It has very good examples for addition, deletion, traversal. Note, the list takes a `void pointer` to a payload struct to generalize the list, but if you wanted you could replace that with a simple `int`. I see a new comment, I'll respond to that next.

Answer (score 0):

```
    trashCurr = trashHead;
    while(trashCurr != NULL){

        trashCurr = trashCurr -> next;
    }

    trashCurr -> next = curr;
```

At the end of the `while` loop, `trashCurr` is definitely `NULL`. So trying to assign something to `rtashCurr->next` will crash. Maybe you want:

```
    trashCurr = trashHead;
    while(trashCurr -> next != NULL){

        trashCurr = trashCurr -> next;
    }

    trashCurr -> next = curr;
```

Comment: Yup, i noticed that a little while ago but forgot to update the code. Good catch :)